# android:isolatedProcess="true" crashing the Service

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-service

I am trying to start service in a separate process, so that it will run even after user close the application.

I google it, and found some solution. I adopted following, but its crashing the service.

I have added  following in my `Manifest` file

```
 <service android:name=".myservices.services.LocationUpdateService"
        android:process=":locationservice"
        android:isolatedProcess="true"
        />
```

If i remove the last 2 lines, it starts the service successfully, but stop it onDestroy of application.

This is how i am starting the service.

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationUpdateService.class);
                    startService(intent);
```

Kindly guide me what additional steps i need to make to start it in separate process.

Comment: crashing? what's the logcat output?

Comment: logcat is not showing anything. application is also not crashing, but it gives the error message `Unfortunately, Application has stopped`

Comment: I am not sure you want to use isolatedProcess, your use case is for: android:process

Comment: @Kirmani88 add your service class code for more details.